# How do I make a cefpython Kivy widget

Tags: python, kivy, cefpython

I am trying to embed a browser using cefpython3 within my kivy application - I don't need a ton of functionality (I just need the browser to run some javascript for me).

I downloaded the cefpython3 repo and got the [hello_world.py](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/hello_world.py) to work, and now I am simply trying to get that window that pops up into a kivy widget.

The examples seem pretty dated and people are saying that they only developed in certain environments - what would I have to do/learn to make a widget and drop this browser in there?

Comment: See the official example: https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/src/linux/binaries_64bit/kivy_.py

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but with no luck, the program will say it cannot find _event.pyx in kivy, among other challenges / errors

Comment: It is also only tested on linux, while my operating platform is windows. If I can build the widget from scratch and embed what I need to, that will help me farther i believe

Comment: change `self.browser_widget = CefBrowser(id="browser")` to  `self.browser_widget = CefBrowser()`

Comment: 1) You will be the first to test it on windows, 2) but I doubt that you will be the first since according to the  `elif sys.platform == 'darwin' or sys.platform == 'win32':` command I see that they have thought about windows 3) I think it should work since the logic is simple: get the cef buffer and only using a texture for painting in kivy.

Comment: I'm genuinely shocked - i spent a few hours last night but it worked. Why would removing `id="browser"` change so much/fix my issue?

Comment: It is that kivy uses the kwargs to handle the bindings (events) but the event or property "id" does not exist, so it throws that error. Recommendation: report that bug to cefpython